# Need help selecting XSLT with xsl:choose and xsl/when

Tags: php, xslt

My XSLT language isn't good - so any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm trying to select the reviews from the XML file (file.xml) below that only have a description count less than 100 words and also if a description is missing don't select it at all (you'll notice the 2nd item in the xml that the description is missing)

I've messed around ***xsl:choose*** and ***xsl/when*** but still can't seem to get this working correctly.

**Load the XML file using PHP**

```
$xmlFile = 'file.xml';
                   
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
                    
$doc->load($xslFile);
$xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
                    
$doc->load($xmlFile);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

**Here is my XML (file.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>Reviews</title>
        <description>5 Star Reviews</description>
        <link></link>
        <item>
            <title>Google review 4 stars - John</title>
            <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico quaestio eu vis. Errem disputationi mel te, in civibus minimum qualisque vel. </description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Google review 5 stars - Sarah</title>
            <description></description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Google review 5 stars - Jenny</title>
            <description>I love this place! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico quaestio eu vis. Errem disputationi mel te, in civibus minimum qualisque vel. Et duo quando detracto tacimates, mediocrem instructior id pro. Nec id omnis aperiri iracundia,</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**The XSLT file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
    
    <li>
        <p class="heading">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </p>

        <p class="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </p>
    </li>
    
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My final output should look like this.**

Google review 4 stars - John
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico quaestio eu vis. Errem disputationi mel te, in civibus minimum qualisque vel.

Google review 5 stars - Jenny
I love this place! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico quaestio eu vis. Errem disputationi mel te, in civibus minimum qualisque vel. Et duo quando detracto tacimates, mediocrem instructior id pro. Nec id omnis aperiri iracundia,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to start with a predicate on the `item` selection e.g. `item[description[normalize-space()]]` selects only the `item` elements having a `description` child which has more than white space content.

As for counting words, that is more difficult to express in XPath 1.0. As you seem to do it from PHP, check whether PHP exposes libxslt's EXSLT extension functions or alternatively call into PHP to and count words in the description content.

To use PHP's `str_word_count` function with XSLTProcessor you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="php"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[description[normalize-space() and php:function('str_word_count', string()) &lt; 100]]">
            
            <li>
                <p class="heading">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </p>
                
                <p class="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                </p>
            </li>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and in the PHP code you need

```
$xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

$xsltProcessor->registerPHPFunctions();
```

I also think you would better create two different DOMDocument objects, one for the XML input and one for the XSLT document.

Comment: You cannot use regex with EXSLT `str:split()`. The expression `str:split(., '\W+')"` looks for a literal string `"\W+"`. -- I don't think the 100 words limit needs to be taken literally; counting the spaces should be sufficient, IMHO. That can be done with no extensions.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, ok, sorry about that, the description saying "pattern" for the argument made me assume I could throw in a regular expression pattern. Will edit to use a PHP function instead.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Perfect! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help :)